# JSON array of objects in vapor

Tags: json, swift, vapor

Maybe it's a noob question, but I can't find any solution anywhere else, so I want to ask.

I'm trying to generate JSON formatted data with Vapor in swift.

I have a class, named Customer and a class, named Parcel
In Customer class, I have a variable 
`var parcelArray = [Parcel]`
I added a parcels in that array in 'drop.get'
Now I want to generate JSON

```
 return try Node(node:[ 
        "firstName" : self.firstName,
        "lastName" : self.lastName,
        "personID" : self.personID
    ])
```

How can I add `parcelArray` here? I want result like this:

```
{"name": "Name",
    "surname": "Surname",
    "person_id": 123123123,
    "parcel": [
       "parcelName": "parcel 1"
    ],
    "parcel": [
       "parcelName" : "parcel 2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're already using the vapor/node project. Have you seen this? https://github.com/vapor/json

Comment: @DaveWeston
Yes, it's a solution - 
`"parcel": try JSON(node:[
                "test": self.intermedCountry?[1].IntermedCountryName                
                ])`
But now I'm in another trouble.. How can I make nodes of every array elements inside a node? I cant use 'in' statement inside another node?

Comment: I don't understand your follow up question. Can you post the current output you're getting and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

The array stuff can be a little bit tricky because at this time, generic extensions can't then conform to a protocol. In Swift 4, they will function interchangeably, in the meantime, we have a little extra work to do.

```
 return try Node(node:[ 
        "firstName" : self.firstName,
        "lastName" : self.lastName,
        "personID" : self.personID,
        "parcels": self.parcels.makeNode()
    ])
```

Let me know if that's not clear and we can be more specific re: JSON